# Sorting a list using sorted() by passing a list as the key argument

Tags: python, list, sorting, key

I've got a list which contains all cards from a standard 52 cards deck. I'm now wondering how i could sort these cards after their values, from Aces to Kings. My Idea was to use sorted() but I'm failing to grasp how I could pass the order of the list blueprint_deck as the key for the function.

My Script:

```
import random

Clubs = ["Clubs"]
Diamonds = ["Diamonds"]
Hearts = ["Hearts"]
Spades = ["Spades"]

blueprint_deck = [ "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
                   "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]

deck = [i + " of " + j for i in blueprint_deck for j in Clubs + Diamonds + Hearts + Spades]

print(deck)
```

This would already return the deck sorted, but I want to know how I could achieve this order with a function after randomizing the list for example:

```
random_list = random.sample(deck, len(deck))
print(random_list)
```

What kind of function would I need to pass to the key argument of sorted() to achieve my goal?
I've tried something like this:

```
def keyf(blueprint_deck):
    return blueprint_deck

print(sorted(random_list, key=keyf))
```

But that just seems to sort it in the default order of sorted().

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: ``keyf`` returns its argument unchanged. That is the default behaviour of ``sorted``'s ``key``. You would have to compute the value of the card instead of just returning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd solve this task by assigning numerical weights for every card. Something like that:

```
weight = {"Ace": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4,
          "5": 5, "6": 6, "7": 7, "8": 8, 
          "9": 9, "10": 10, "Jack": 11,
          "Queen": 12, "King": 14}

def keyf(card):
    return weight[card.split()[0]]

print(sorted(random_list, key=keyf))
```

The function specified via `key` param is invoked for every element in the list. The idea is to assign some kind of rank to every element. However, since elements represented as plain text, we need to parse it first taking only the leftmost part.

**UPD:** Some extra explanation of the idea.

Imagine, you have a list of pairs. The nature of the list doesn't really matter, so let it consists of pairs like this `[('jack', 11), ('ace', 1), ('queen', 12)]`. If you want to sort the list by using only the second element from each pair (I call it *a rank*), you need to teach `sorted()` function to consider only at the second element (i.e. *rank*) while sorting the list:

```
lst = [('jack', 11), ('ace', 1), ('queen', 12)]
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda c: c[1])
```

It's a common technique, at least in the Python world.

Now, getting back to the original task, you don't really have a list of pairs. Rather you have a list of strings of the following format `"Ace of Clubs"`, `"2 of Diamonds"`, etc. So, first, you need to convert every element to a pair by splitting the string on whitespace. Then, since you're interested in the rank, you need to map the left part (e.g. `"Ace"` or `"2"`) to the numeric rank. For that, I use a dict mapping of such left parts to the corresponding numeric rank value.

Comment: This works great, thank you very much! Could you possibly elaborate on why weight[card.split()[0]] does what we want it to do? I'm whacking my brain but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to sort by the position of the value in the list; `deck.index`. Here's an example:

```
suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]

blueprint_deck = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
                  "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]

deck = [i + " of " + j for i in blueprint_deck for j in suits]

test = ["8 of Spades", "9 of Spades", "Ace of Diamonds", "King of Hearts"]

print(test)
print(sorted(test, key = deck.index))
```

Output:

```
['8 of Spades', '9 of Spades', 'Ace of Diamonds', 'King of Hearts']
['Ace of Diamonds', '8 of Spades', '9 of Spades', 'King of Hearts']
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Is there a way of using the index of blueprint_deck? From my understanding your solution would only work if we already had a presorted deck like in my script, but I suppose it wouldn't work if we were presented with only a randomized deck.

Comment: If you don't want to compute the full deck, but have blueprint_deck and suits, you can instead sort the list twice; first sort by suits.index, then by blueprint_deck.index. That will have the same effect. However, note that e.g. "King of Hearts" is not in the suits list. So before passing to suits.index, you should extract just the suit from the card. For example, key = lambda x: suits.index(x.split(" of ")[1]). Same applies for the blueprint_list step.

Answer (score 0):

Check my solution

```
orderTable = {"Ace": 0, "Jack": 10, "Queen": 11, "King": 12, "Clubs": 0, "Diamonds": 1,
  "Hearts": 2, "Spades": 3}

def cardOrder(card):
  (f,x,s) = card.split()
  n = orderTable[f] if f in orderTable else int(f) - 1
  return n * 4 + orderTable[s]

def sort_deck(deck_list):
  sorted_list = list(range(13 * 4))
  for card in deck_list: 
    sorted_list[cardOrder(card)] = card;
  return sorted_list
```

Test

```
print(deck, end="\n---Shuffled deck---\n")
print(random_list, end="\n---Ordered once again---\n")
print(sort_deck(random_list))
```

Output

```
['Ace of Clubs', 'Ace of Diamonds', 'Ace of Hearts', 'Ace of Spades', '2 of Clubs',
 '2 of Diamonds', '2 of Hearts', '2 of Spades', '3 of Clubs', '3 of Diamonds',
 '3 of Hearts', '3 of Spades', '4 of Clubs', '4 of Diamonds', '4 of Hearts',
 '4 of Spades', '5 of Clubs', '5 of Diamonds', '5 of Hearts', '5 of Spades',
 '6 of Clubs', '6 of Diamonds', '6 of Hearts', '6 of Spades', '7 of Clubs',
 '7 of Diamonds', '7 of Hearts', '7 of Spades', '8 of Clubs', '8 of Diamonds',
 '8 of Hearts', '8 of Spades', '9 of Clubs', '9 of Diamonds', '9 of Hearts',
 '9 of Spades', '10 of Clubs', '10 of Diamonds', '10 of Hearts', '10 of Spades',
 'Jack of Clubs', 'Jack of Diamonds', 'Jack of Hearts', 'Jack of Spades',
 'Queen of Clubs', 'Queen of Diamonds', 'Queen of Hearts', 'Queen of Spades',
 'King of Clubs', 'King of Diamonds', 'King of Hearts', 'King of Spades']
---Shuffled deck---
['9 of Spades', '5 of Hearts', 'King of Clubs', '9 of Diamonds', '6 of Diamonds',
 'Ace of Spades', '5 of Diamonds', '3 of Clubs', '5 of Spades', '7 of Hearts',
 'Queen of Spades', '4 of Hearts', 'Jack of Spades', '7 of Spades', '4 of Spades',
 'King of Hearts', 'King of Spades', 'Jack of Clubs', '4 of Clubs', '3 of Hearts',
 '2 of Clubs', '2 of Hearts', 'Queen of Hearts', 'Ace of Diamonds', 'Jack of Hearts',
 '10 of Clubs', '8 of Diamonds', '7 of Diamonds', '10 of Hearts', '10 of Diamonds',
 'King of Diamonds', '5 of Clubs', 'Ace of Hearts', 'Ace of Clubs', '4 of Diamonds',
 '3 of Spades', 'Queen of Diamonds', '2 of Spades', '6 of Spades', '9 of Clubs',
 '8 of Clubs', 'Jack of Diamonds', '3 of Diamonds', '10 of Spades', '2 of Diamonds',
 '7 of Clubs', '6 of Clubs', '8 of Spades', 'Queen of Clubs', '9 of Hearts',
 '6 of Hearts', '8 of Hearts']
---Ordered once again---
['Ace of Clubs', 'Ace of Diamonds', 'Ace of Hearts', 'Ace of Spades', '2 of Clubs',
 '2 of Diamonds', '2 of Hearts', '2 of Spades', '3 of Clubs', '3 of Diamonds',
 '3 of Hearts', '3 of Spades', '4 of Clubs', '4 of Diamonds', '4 of Hearts',
 '4 of Spades', '5 of Clubs', '5 of Diamonds', '5 of Hearts', '5 of Spades',
 '6 of Clubs', '6 of Diamonds', '6 of Hearts', '6 of Spades', '7 of Clubs',
 '7 of Diamonds', '7 of Hearts', '7 of Spades', '8 of Clubs', '8 of Diamonds',
 '8 of Hearts', '8 of Spades', '9 of Clubs', '9 of Diamonds', '9 of Hearts',
 '9 of Spades', '10 of Clubs', '10 of Diamonds', '10 of Hearts', '10 of Spades',
 'Jack of Clubs', 'Jack of Diamonds', 'Jack of Hearts', 'Jack of Spades',
 'Queen of Clubs', 'Queen of Diamonds', 'Queen of Hearts', 'Queen of Spades',
 'King of Clubs', 'King of Diamonds', 'King of Hearts', 'King of Spades']
```